# Liquibase run store procedure returns error

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, liquibase

I try to set up the sql file from changeset to run a store procedure that is saved into my project but it returns sql error.
Here I declared the sqlfile:

```
<sqlFile path="/db/FindAllFriends.sql" endDelimiter="//" relativeToChangelogFile="true" splitStatements="true" stripComments="true" />
```

Here is my procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE aaa()
BEGIN

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

If I let the "delimiter" in script it will return an sql error (you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual....). If I remove it, it will be ok but it works only with ";" delimiter.

If I tried to drop and then create the procedure (or multiple statements):

```
Drop procedure if exists aaa;

CREATE PROCEDURE aaa()

BEGIN

END;
```

I receive: `Error executing sql drop procedure if exists aaa;`

My problem is that I need first to "drop procedure if exists" and after to create it, and I'm forced to use "delimiter" inside of script.

I don't know if it is a problem with the mysql parser, liquibase error or I made a mistake in my script.

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling with procedures (on Oracle) for some time now, and I start to believe that Liquibase was not made with procedures in mind ;)

Anyway - maybe [dropProcedure](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/drop_procedure.html) and [createProcedure](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_procedure.html) changes would be sufficient for you?

I find [executeCommand](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/execute_command.html) change with sqlplus to be the best solution to run scripts on Oracle...

Comment: I have all scripts saved into my java project but when I drop the database only the tables are regenerated, so I need to run all the scripts manually in mysql. I can put in changeset a dropProcedure and a createProcedure for each script, but I like simply to run each script whatever is in it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able run all scripts; I don't know what I made wrong when I tried first time, but now works. I had to declare the endDelimiter in sqlFile and to use this delimiter into script, also I deleted the declaration of "Delimiter //" from script